# xml form design

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I just started coding xml in Android Studio and I would like to create a form where each field has the design shown on the image. My problem is to put the field name on the border of the field box. How can I do that ? Could someone give me a code to achieve that pls.

Thanks !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uPe8.png)

I tried relativeLayout and AlignLayout but nothing is working

Comment: Look at [`TextInputLayout'](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields) - it has many options for making inputs like that without needing custom drawables or your own RelativeLayout

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a round-corner border for the background in `res/drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

You will first have to align the start and top of the label to that of EditText, and then use padding and margin combiation of achieve the required layout. To shift the layout upwards you will have to use negative margin value.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_poll_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:hint="Enter you poll title..."
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_poll_title"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/input_poll_title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/input_poll_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Poll Title"
        android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]

**Alternative Approach** : Since this will end up having to manually create and align the lable for each of your EditText. Maybe you can use the `TextInputLayout` by Material Design, which is the recommeded design guidelines for Android by Google.

You can read more about the different TextInputLayout Designs [here](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I do that, the top of "Poll Title" is getting cutted of. Maybe it's because I'm working in a LinearLayout ?

Comment: You cannot align view on top of each other in `LinearLayout`. You must use `RelativeLayout` for this.